# Reseed SQL server statement throwing error Incorrect Syntax near

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I've got my code set up like this:

```
using (MyDataContext TheDC = new MyDataContext())
{
     TheDC.ExecuteCommand("CHECKIDENT('SomeTableName', RESEED, 1)");
     TheDC.SubmitChanges();
}
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'SomeTableName'.

I looked online and the syntax seems fine, but it's not; what do I need to change?

Comment: Is an identity reseed so frequent that you need to add functionality to your application to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using (MyDataContext TheDC = new MyDataContext())
{
     TheDC.ExecuteCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT('SomeTableName', RESEED, 1)");
     TheDC.SubmitChanges();
}
```